# Setting form data in clean_field method

Tags: python, django

Suppose there's a model:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    content = models.FileField(...)
    number_of_lines = models.IntegerField()
```

I use a `ModelForm` and a `content` field is validated in the `client_content()` method. Also I count the number of lines in `content` and I want to use this number to set the field's `number_of_lines` value:

What I came up with is:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_content(self):
        self.number_of_lines = 0
        # validation
            self.number_of_lines +=1
        # ...

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super().save(commit=True)
        instance.number_of_lines = self.number_of_lines
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

But that `self.number_of_lines` thing does not look right. Is there a better way? Maybe it's possible to set `self.cleaned_data['number_of_accounts']` in the `clean_content` method?

Usually people suggest to use `clean()` method to do that, but in this case I have to remove the line counter from `clean_content` and count the lines inside `clean()`.

Comment: How about using Django pre signal https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save ? Before saving, you can add the code to count the number of lines and save it.

Comment: @Edwin Lunando where should I keep the calculated `number_of_lines` then? Before it gets saved in a signal.